# Minecraft Launcher Java Error- java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

When I start my Minecraft Launcher I get an error specifically shown below:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
```

The full error is shown below:

```
[22:43:22 INFO]: JFX has been detected & successfully loaded 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Refreshing local version list... 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.3.11 (through bootstrap 5) started on windows... 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Current time is Apr 6, 2014 10:43:24 PM 
[22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_51' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation' [22:43:24 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list... 
[22:43:24 ERROR]: Unexpected exception refreshing version list java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create  at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Http.performGet(Http.java:56) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.RemoteVersionList.getContent(RemoteVersionList.java:26) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionList.refreshVersions(VersionList.java:77) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionManager.refreshVersions(VersionManager.java:60) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:165) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
[22:43:24 INFO]: Loaded 17 profile(s); selected 'Nodus' 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Refreshing auth... 
[22:43:24 INFO]: Logging in with access token 
[22:43:24 ERROR]: Exception whilst logging into profile com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationUnavailableException: Cannot contact authentication server
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:69) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilUserAuthentication.logInWithToken(YggdrasilUserAuthentication.java:124) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilUserAuthentication.logIn(YggdrasilUserAuthentication.java:53) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher.ensureLoggedIn(Launcher.java:208) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:177) [launcher.jar:?]    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_51] 
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at com.mojang.authlib.HttpAuthenticationService.performPostRequest(HttpAuthenticationService.java:73) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.makeRequest(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:52) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
```

I kept looking for ways, and it didn't work.

Yes, I've tried

- Reinstalling/updating java.
- Messing with firewall/anti-malware stuff.
- Reinstalling the launcher.
- Getting the Windows Update

Other info you may want to know:

- I use malwarebytes to get rid of viruses because I had Adblocknwatch extension virus that couldn't be uninstalled/removed.
- When I got malwarebytes my minecraft stopped working.
- I have AT&T u-verse and my computer [WAS] port-forwarded for my server, I unport-forwarded it to see if it would fix the problem, but it didn't.
- I only have Java jre7 no higher/lower
- This was asked as of April 6th, 2014.

Here is the full bootstrap error thing:

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Apr 12, 2014 12:48:14 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_51'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
Looking for update
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 2/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 3/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 4/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 5/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 6/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 7/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 8/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 9/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 10/10)
Exception: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
Didn't find an update in time.
Reversing LZMA on C:\Users\Alex Chiang\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack.lzma to C:\Users\Alex Chiang\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack
Unpacking C:\Users\Alex Chiang\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.pack to C:\Users\Alex Chiang\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\launcher.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem and solution. It was a malware issue, for others, this maybe you too. So get Microsoft Security Essentials and scan on your computer. After scanning, I found a browser hijack hack thing that was hacking my connection. So when I quarantined it, I fixed it! :D But still have issues with connecting to google and youtube. Hope this helps other people. Even malware-bytes didn't help.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by reinstalling Java:

1. Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features
2. Uninstalled Java and all Java updates
3. Go to [Java's download site](https://java.com/en/download/index.jsp) and reinstalled Java

and bam it worked

Comment: Great answer, it sounds like it would work. But I've studied that this issue can have many cases. Different ways there are to solve it: malware issue- get MSSE, port issue- aiyion-prime's solution, java issue- update. :D Thanks for your contribution though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like too comment this, as this won't be useful that much as first - but im still too jelly for this ;) Sorry.

I'd like to see your Bootstrap or at least your Windows os + Version (32/64).

Without knowing this lets start low.

1. Take a laptop, install the same Version of Minecraft and put it in your Network exactly like you did with your PC. (you connected the pc vial ethernet - plug the pcs lan-Cable in your laptopor if you use w-lan-> use the same accesspoint)
2. If this works, try to alter your PCs ip-address. (some intelligent 
   routers try to prevent you from unwanted ports after your virus-software informs them)
3. Probably your problem isn't solved yet.  The next thing to do is saving your .minecraft folder from appdata to any flashdrive and put it on your test-laptop
4. post your results below

----- update

I got my coffee now, lets go on :)
So you're running Windows7 on a 64bit core - I am sorry, ' have not read this properly first.

This part:

> java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create

means you are failing to open the port.
Usually this has one of two reasons: either you (or any program you installed) blocked the port to protect you, or any program you have got is using the Port right now.

but IIRC the second possibility should have caused something like this:

> ... Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind

But this may have changed due the new launcer, so lets scan the ports.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> --> cmd --> <kbd>enter</kbd>
    netstat -b

This will give you a list of all active Ports and the matching programs using them.

post your reply and we may go on

Comment: I'll make sure to try this when I can. Thanks for the answer and ASA it works then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I did not see a process for the Minecraft Launcher or the game if it was running. So you know a common port the Launcher/game uses? Or should I remove of Malware-bytes?

Comment: The process should be called Minecraft.exe and may be placed anywhere.
And you should be looking for the port 10106 as you've got problems with it.

Have you tried to launch the game on an other device as mentioned above?

Comment: You probably had a pop up about Java using public/private networks. A lot of people don't read before clicking. If you cancelled this the first time, you will get this or failed login. Reinstalling means it asked you again, you maybe made the right choice this time. But it could be something else.